# MAMP Apache will not start - Permission Denied: make_sock

Tags: mysql, apache, mamp

MySQL and PHP was working fine with my MAMP for a very long time, so I really don't know what happened. Now every time when I try to log into my Apache from the terminal I get:

httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using MacBook.local for ServerName (13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80 (13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80 no listening sockets available, shutting down Unable to open logs

(I didn't include the actual name for the server)

I'm using a OS X system with Apache 2.2 and I don't think I properly configured my server. How do I fix this and get back on track? I did delete some of the member access and moved my htdoc files so that I could start over with my files. I believe that is where it turned against me.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a permissions issue. Go to your terminal and have your MAMP status dialog open.

First issue:

```
sudo apachectl -k stop
```

then

```
sudo apachectl -k start
```

what you're doing is you're using sudo to get root permissions. See if that helps.

Comment: Ok, so I used sudo and I got:  WARNING: Improper use of the sudo command could lead to data loss
or the deletion of important system files. Please double-check your
typing when using sudo. Type "man sudo" for more information.   I don't remember my password.  So what now?

To proceed, enter your password, or type Ctrl-C to abort.

Password:     I don't remember my password so what now?

Comment: Also, thank you so much unixmiah for the help.  I really appreciated the assistance.  Now I just have to figure out how to get past the password.  I'm going to go back into phpMyAdmin to work on that.

Comment: I don't know what happened, but now phpMyAdmin now will not activate giving me an error message:   Error
MySQL said: 

#2002 - Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).     I made changes to the users log and then tried to open from terminal again, but terminal is showing blank and I still cannot open MySQL from MAMP.

Comment: Do I need to reload my MAMP and start from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

Rename the file envvars located in /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin into _envvars It worked for me. You may need to restart.

Comment: I know it's been a while, but I finally figured out my problem.  At first I deleted my MAMP and downloaded another version and I thought that would solve my problem.  But it didn't.  I then couldn't get into MySQL, because I had forgotten my root login information.  I tried everything until I finally ran into a code that allowed me to change my root password.  Then I still wasn't able to get in.  Not until I finally realized that I was not suppose to enter my password after -u root -p.  I was supposed to hit enter and enter my password after I was prompted to.  Now I'm back in business!